# why do i get this error when pulling an image in docker

Tags: linux, docker, raspbian, portainer

i try to pull a image with:

```
$ docker pull ghcr.io/linuxserver/nextcloud:latest
```

but i get this error message:

Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": dial tcp:
lookup ghcr.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:41228->[::1]:53: read:
connection refused

Comment: Well port 53 is DNS related. Are you able to resolve the IP of that domain?

Answer (score 4):

Well, it seems that your Linux kernel have tried to establish TCP connection with DNS server, but DNS server did not accept the connection. It can be becuase of multiple reasons. My suggestions is:

1. Check out your **/etc/resolve.conf** file, perhaps it points out on an irrelevant server. If this is so, try to use **resolvconf** utility (it may not be installed on your host, so use **apt** or **yum** in order to install it) to generate the content of /etc/resolve.conf on boot time properly. I mean, if this is the case, set `nameserver 8.8.8.8` by the means of resolvconf can solve you problem. You technically can edit /etc/reslve.conf manually in order to make this changes, **but it will work only till the next reboot**.
2. If it is self-hosted DNS server (BIND9 for example), then check the firewall rules on host of your DNS server. Perhaps there are iptables filter rules that reject that kind of traffic. And, of course, check out **named.conf** configuration (I mean the upstream request forwarding, allow-query ip addreses and so on)
3. Check out your **systemd-resolved**. It should be healthy and running, since it manages local dns cache and e.t.c.