# Why docker not working in manjaro, connection refuzed

Tags: linux, docker, daemon, manjaro

Every action throws an error.

For example:

```
[greenjoy@greenjoyPC ~]$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:50383->[::1]:53: read: connection refused.
```

Some information:

```
[greenjoy@greenjoyPC ~]$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.13.0)
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc., v0.0.5)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.16)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.22.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc version: 
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.81-1-MANJARO
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 18
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 11.58GiB
 Name: greenjoyPC
 ID: 7JRW:4CYG:5CUT:PC2B:HOVA:7OPT:I6PR:3AD5:DYD7:2FOK:MVMU:ZCYH
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

And docker-desktop won't load no matter how long you wait.Just docker desktop starting...

Tried several ways from different sources but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Manjaro and after starting the daemon and putting my user into the docker-group everything works as expected (using your particular docker run command).

However, from your error message, it rather looks like a connectivity problem to the server docker repositories. You may check on your firewalls whether connections are blocked.

There is a similar case here, where setting a different DNS server seemed to work: [why do i get this error when pulling an image in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216381/why-do-i-get-this-error-when-pulling-an-image-in-docker)

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with the connection and I do not understand exactly where and why, Firefall disabled                                                                                       
ERROR: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60519->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

Comment: it seems somehow DNS-related... did you try to set your DNS server temporarily to something else e.g. https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062 ?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a fresh docker install and I couldn't reach other websites after that. After some searching (on a different computer:-) I tried this:

```
docker network prune
```

Now other IP addresses are resolving again.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue, for some reason docker was not runnin on my machine, so i did:

`sudo pacman -Syu`

`sudo pacman -S docker`

`sudo systemctl start docker.service`

and then

`sudo docker run hello-world`